# How to integrate tabular data into GraphDB automatically?

Tags: rdf, data-integration, openrefine, graphdb

I want to import tabular (xls) data automatically into GraphDB. OntoRefine suits my case very will with the power of OpenRefine and SPARQL.

Now, i am thinking about the following approach

- New tabular data is available as XLS file
- OntoRefine updates a project or creates a new project automatically
- SPARQL queries against RDFbridge to create new triples
- SPARQL Insert to add this triple

Is there an alternative approach to automate it?
If this is the best, how can i update or create a new OntoRefine project automatically (utilizing some kind of API)?

Comment: You should be able to use the OpenRefine API for that, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53829569/how-can-i-access-the-api-of-ontorefine